# Some javascript functions are not working on github pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, github

Some javascript functions in my main.js file isnt working when I am hosting the site through github pages. Like the one to prevent right click.

```
window.oncontextmenu=function(){
    return false;
}
```

The other functions for hover and unhover are taking somewhat taking time to execute. I am just github pages as a prototype. Will this issue be resolved when I host from a proper server?

Comment: The Javascript is running in the browser, so it really shouldn't matter what server it came from. I'd wager this is just a problem with your code, could you post more of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The window doesn't has the oncontextmenu callback, instead you should attach a listener to the document :

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
        alert("You've tried to open context menu"); //here you draw your own menu
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
} else {
    document.attachEvent('oncontextmenu', function() {
        alert("You've tried to open context menu");
        window.event.returnValue = false;
    });
}
```

Besides, there's no way that Github Pages can be related to a JS issue.

Comment: Thank you bro. This did work. Can you also help me why javascript hover functions are taking time to execute?
The code is like this: 
function hover(element) {
    element.setAttribute('src', 'assets/li.svg');
}
function unhover(element) {
    element.setAttribute('src', 'assets/uli.svg');
}

I am calling them by onmouseover="hover(this)" and onmouseleave="unhover(this)" in my index.html file

Comment: Github pages had some JS library code a wee bit different than I had it locally due to a Git submodule's content not properly synchronised, that's why it didn't work in my case. There was no kind of JS error or warning messages. It looked so like a JS related issue though. I mean, differences in JS code just has to look like a JS related issue, right? :)